# My programm doesn't click on checkbox properly

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium-chromedriver.

```
checkbox = driver.find_element_by_name('hidedup')
print(checkbox.location)
```

it will output coordinates like these(by means of Page Ruler extension):
[image]

[image]

I was trying(when the corrdinates were the same as in the second picture):

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(checkbox, 5, -5).click().perform()
```

but it didn't help

html code of the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hidedup" onchange="window.onchangehidedup(event)">
```

Also, the problem didn't occur when I was using Firefox driver

I've been trying to figure out how to solve it for 2 days already, I ask for your help

Comment: What happens if you just click the checkbox - `checkbox.click()`? Also, is the checkbox label clickable? And, please post the HTML representation of the checkbox. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing happens. That's why I decided to try ActionChains(). The label is not clickable. the HTML representation is now in my first post.

Comment: if its not clickable, then why do you want to make that click at first?

Comment: The checkbox is clickable, the label isn't ("Hide duplicate, show .....").

Comment: why am I downvoted? Just because the chromedriver has some bugs? I've already pointed that everything went smooth while using firefox driver

Comment: May be it's possible to execute onchange event somehow?

Comment: Before going on this coordinates research, which is the last resort usually, did you try the usual stuff, i.e. waiting for element to become clickable, trying to select it by keyboard rather than click ( `driver.find_element_by_name('hidedup').send_keys(Keys.SPACE)`) and trying to set it by JS (`driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('hidedup')[0].checked = true;")`)

Comment: I should have known that it's also possible to select an element by pressing SPACE button. It worked finally. Thank you very much! Still can't understand why it doesn't react on usual clicks . You can write your post as the asnwer, and then I will mark it as the right one